# ReferenceError when using c++ and qml on Nokia N9

Tags: c++, qml

I want to integrate [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [qml](/questions/tagged/qml). However, my code works fine in simulator but not in `Nokia N9` (`Qt 4.7.4 harmattan_10.2011.34-1`)

Here is my code
I pasted c++ and qml code here for your reference

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeView>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeContext>
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeEngine>
#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"
#include "data.h"
#include "testfactory.h"
Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));
TestFactory *testfactory = new TestFactory();
QScopedPointer<QmlApplicationViewer> viewer(QmlApplicationViewer::create());
QDeclarativeContext *context = viewer->rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("testfactory", testfactory);
viewer->setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationLockPortrait);
viewer->setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/main.qml"));
viewer->showExpanded();
testfactory->intilize();
return app->exec();
}



Button {
    id: startButton
    text: qsTr("Start")
    onClicked: {
        mainview.state = "START"
        testfactory.startMeasurement()    
    }
}
```

The wield part is that the code works on simulator but the device.
The error I get is ReferenceError: Can't find variable: testfactory

Any one knows what the reason is?

Comment: Have you tried using a different variable name for `test` and see if the error uses that name?

Comment: I think we'd likely need to see where test was referenced in the qml as well.  [I'd always shy away from "test" as it's rather generic and could conflict with something else.]

Comment: Also, what's the wrapping scope of the above?  Because showExpanded() will return immediately, so I hope you're doing app.exec() after that or something?

Comment: @Wes Hardaker, I modify my question and include the missing parts you mentioned.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie different names give still the same result

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments from irc qt-qml, one solution is to just use

```
QmlApplicationViewer *viewer = new QmlApplicationViewer();
```

instead of

```
QScopedPointer<QmlApplicationViewer> viewer(QmlApplicationViewer::create());
```

Then code works.